# Java user input validations

Tags: java, validation, netbeans

I'm new to Java GUI . I'm doing a project using Netbeans.There are several text fields and I need to do validations for them.

Validations should be

- Want to check whether fields are empty or not.
- If it's a number field it should be validated only to input numbers.

In web (Ex:contact form) validations we can validate the fields step by step when user is entering data up to down. I need to know whether it is possible or not in Java GUI programmes.

Found several methods as Documentfilter,InputVerifier and PlainDocument. Can someone please explain the differences of them and what is the best method to use for validations input data of users in Java?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

depending how familiar you are with java programming in general, this helps you more or less

1. Retrieve the text from the JTextField (`getText()`) and check for emptiness
2. Cast the text to a number and catch a `NumberFormatException` in case its not a number.

for 2) its a validation after the user has entered something and not an validation during typing

Comment: Thank you very much . This helps me to continue my task.

Answer (score 1):

You should write java method for validation .
1.Read Text from JTextField using (getText() ) and pass this string to NumberValidation Method . Sample code is shown below

```
String  data=textFieldObject.getText().trim();
boolean validate =isValidMobile(data);//return false if the data is not a valid phone number

    public  boolean isValidMobile(String PhoneNumber)
        {
    try{
            if(PhoneNumber.length()==10) //checking length.
            {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            char c=PhoneNumber.charAt(i);   
            if(!Character.isDigit(c)) //return false if the character is digit
            {
                return false;
            }
            }
            }else
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            }catch(Exception r)
    {
    return false;
    }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer also helps me.